# How do I know if a link has the "active" class?

Tags: 8, theming

I've added a custom twig template for links--language-block.html.twig.

Inside of it, I want to render additional HTML when the current item is active. But I can't figure out how to check when the current item is active.

```
{% if links -%}
  {%- if attributes.hasClass('inline') -%}
  <ul{{ attributes.addClass('list-inline') }}>
  {%- else -%}
  <ul{{ attributes }}>
  {%- endif -%}
    {%- for key, item in links -%}

      {% if item.attributes.hasClass('is-active') %} << this is always false
        <li>foobar</li>
      {%- endif -%}

      <li{{ item.attributes.addClass('dropdown') }}>
        {%- if item.link -%}
          {{ item.link }}

          {# <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Deutsch <span class="caret"></span></a> #}
        {%- elseif item.text_attributes -%}
          <span{{ item.text_attributes }}>{{ item.text }}</span>
        {%- else -%}
          {{ item.text }}
        {%- endif -%}
      </li>
    {%- endfor -%}
  </ul>
{%- endif %}
```

How can I check if the link as the *active* class?

Comment: When you inspect element, do you see the `is-active` class?

Comment: @NoSssweat in the end result yes, but not in the twig template. even using `kint` the final `a` tag has not the active class, only in the browser. it is not javascript, i've checked that

Comment: An alternative would be to **get the current page url or the node title** and use that as your if statement.

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you manage to figure out why this is not working?

Comment: Having the same issue here. I'm still looking into where the is-active class is coming from.

Comment: The active class is not (always) rendered on server-side, see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21LinkGenerator.php/function/LinkGenerator%3A%3Agenerate/8.2.x and the magic regarding `set_active_class`. But I also don't know how to reliably check for active classes.

Comment: In the end the best choice maybe is to do this via JS.

Comment: @leymannx, yes, this is the best choice. For anonymous requests there is also a PHP option in a response subscriber, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/235108/47547

Answer (score 3):

In some cases, the active state is not set by design due potential problems with caching. This behavior is documented in this [change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2167077).

> Setting the active class is now an opt-in feature:
>
> l() and LinkGenerator::generate() now have a set_active_class option that defaults to FALSE
>   theme_links() now accepts a set_active_class key that defaults to FALSE
>   Those links that you'd expect to get the active class set, do get it: menu links, language switching links …
>
> The output of l(), LinkGenerator::generate() and theme_links() no longer contains the active class, even if you do opt in. Instead, they get a data-drupal-link-system-path attribute, and if there's a GET query, they also get a data-drupal-link-query attribute…

In those cases, where it is not set on server side, you can take a look at [core/misc/active-link.js](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/8.7.x/core/misc/active-link.js) to get an idea how to manipulate the active state on client side.

Comment: Yes this behaviour can be confusing to those of us used to how things worked in previous versions of Drupal. Wasted a lot of time figuring this out for myself.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can just use "is_active". This works for me:

```
{% set link = link|merge({ '#attributes': { 'class': [ 'classes', 'if', 'active'] } }) %}
{% if is_active %}
{% set link = link|merge({ '#attributes': { 'class': [ 'classes', 'if', 'not', 'active'] } }) %}
{% endif %}

<li{{ attributes.addClass('nav-item') }} role="presentation">{{ link }}</li>
```

Comment: Really? Even in a cached and unauthenticated session?

Comment: Cant find a menu where I use this where the user is not logged in. Will get back to you if I find a case.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 8 the "is-active" class is added in two different ways:

- For anonymous users it's added in the server side.
- For authenticated users it's using javascript to add the class, as this allows for better cacheability.

You might consider adding the `<li>` in JS when the DOM is ready, to make sure the class has been added to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

For `core/themes/classy/templates/navigation/menu.html.twig`:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override to display a menu.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - menu_name: The machine name of the menu.
 * - items: A nested list of menu items. Each menu item contains:
 *   - attributes: HTML attributes for the menu item.
 *   - below: The menu item child items.
 *   - title: The menu link title.
 *   - url: The menu link url, instance of \Drupal\Core\Url
 *   - localized_options: Menu link localized options.
 *   - is_expanded: TRUE if the link has visible children within the current
 *     menu tree.
 *   - is_collapsed: TRUE if the link has children within the current menu tree
 *     that are not currently visible.
 *   - in_active_trail: TRUE if the link is in the active trail.
 */
#}
```

Then you can write:

```
{% if item.in_active_trail %}
   <li>foobar</li>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a JS library with a dependency on the `core/drupal.active-link` library:

*mytheme/mytheme.libraries.yml*

```
remove-active-links:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/remove-active-links.js: { }
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupal.active-link
```

Then your JS code knows which link has an `is-active` class and you can add HTML or remove the link wrapper like in this example:

*mytheme/js/remove-active-links.js*

```
(function ($, Drupal) {

  'use strict';

  Drupal.behaviors.removeActiveLinks = {
    attach: function (context) {

      $(context).find('a.is-active').contents().unwrap();

    }
  };

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

For more info and an alternative PHP solution (only for anonymous requests) see this answer [Don't link menu in the active page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/235072/dont-link-menu-in-the-active-page/235108#235108)